# Android PopupMenu checkable item does not check

Tags: android, checkbox, popupmenu

I have this simple PopupMenu, but when I click on an item, the item doesn't get checked. Why?

In documentation is:
Menu items in the Icon Menu (from the options menu) cannot display a checkbox or radio button.
Radio button is showing, but only state is not changing...

Java

```
public void showSortPopup() {
    View menuItemView = findViewById(R.id.action_sort);
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, menuItemView);
    popup.inflate(R.menu.sort);
    popup.getMenu().findItem(R.id.sort_def).setChecked(true);
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.sort_def:
                    sortOrder = CardCursorContract.CardCursor.DEFAULT_SORT;
                    mCardsFragment.setSortOrder(sortOrder);
                    savePref();
                    if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
                    else item.setChecked(true);
                    break;
                case R.id.sort_asc:
                    sortOrder = CardCursorContract.CardCursor.ALPHABETICAL_ASC_SORT;
                    mCardsFragment.setSortOrder(sortOrder);
                    savePref();
                    if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
                    else item.setChecked(true);
                    break;
                case R.id.sort_desc:
                    sortOrder = CardCursorContract.CardCursor.ALPHABETICAL_DESC_SORT;
                    mCardsFragment.setSortOrder(sortOrder);
                    savePref();
                    if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
                    else item.setChecked(true);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    popup.show();
}
```

XML-File

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
<item android:id="@+id/sort_def"
      android:title="@string/action_sort_def"
      android:orderInCategory="1"
      android:showAsAction="always" />

<item android:id="@+id/sort_asc"
      android:title="@string/action_sort_name"
      android:orderInCategory="2"
      android:showAsAction="always" />

<item
      android:id="@+id/sort_desc"
      android:title="@string/action_sort_name_desc"
      android:orderInCategory="3"
      android:showAsAction="always"/>
</group>
```

Screen

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you can simplify the if checked else statement to

```
item.setChecked(!item.isChecked())
```

That way it will always toggle it from true → false and the other way around.

But the problem lies in the fact that you have radiobuttons, what the statement above does is makes the `group` checked, but what you want is to have the `item` checked.

To get the behaviour youre looking for you can use `item.getSubmMenu()` and then use the setChecked method on the particular subMenuItem you want.

For example:

```
//This will refer to the default, ascending or descending item.
MenuItem subMenuItem = item.getSubMenu().getItem(INDEX_OF_ITEM); 
//Check or uncheck it.
subMenuItem.setChecked(!subMenuItem.isChecked());
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swap These Lines in every case **

```
if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
                    else item.setChecked(true);
```

**To**

```
if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(true);
                    else item.setChecked(false);
```